# Is the a way to store and reprocess an AST subgraph?

Tags: antlr

I am designing a declarative language. In my language are definitions of "nodes" that can be reused later. Think of them like prototypes or templates. You can create copies of them as needed. I have a version of the interpreter that generates the appropriate Java objects during the definition phase. Up until recently I have been using a deep copy library to create copies of the Java representation of the nodes to create instances of the node. Due to the limitations of most of the deep copying libraries I have found and my lack of desire to write a copy constructor for every object in my system, I want to take a different approach. Part of my language specifies GUI Java Swing objects which cause issues with the deep copy libraries.

Is there a way I can save the AST subgraph for my object declaration and reprocess it when I want to create an instance of the node? I am asking the question in terms of ANTLR ASTs, but if you have a language implementation advice I welcome that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ANTLR parser/lexer grammar, you have access to a `$ruleName.tree`. This rule attribute is the reference to AST subtree generated during parsing. Using the `@after` field and the `@members` field, you can store the subtree. Let me show you.

```
@members{
private List<CommonTree> defs = new ArrayList<CommonTree>();

public List<CommonTree> getDefs(){
    return defs;
}

}
```

below in your grammar

```
ruleName 
@after{
    defs.add($ruleName.tree);
}
: IDENT ;
```

This will create a list of all the ruleName AST subtrees. These trees can be turned into CommonTreeNodeStream and used with your tree grammar code.

```
CommonTree defTree = Parser.getDefs().get(0); // just getting the first tree for example
CommonTreeNodeStream defStream = new CommonTreeNodeStream(defTree);
TreeWalker walker = new TreeWalker(defStream);
//assuming that I have a tree grammar that has been defined to return a list of nodes
```

See [this question for more info on returning data from an ANTLR grammar rule.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909007/how-can-i-get-information-out-of-a-tree-parser-using-the-antlr-tree-grammar-synt?rq=1)

```
List<Node> nodes = walker.topRule()
```

This will allow you to create node instances by reprocessing saved AST subgraphs. You can create the TreeNodeStream and call the walker whenever you need to create an instance.